# What is the scope of a Lua variable?

Tags: lua

I would be really interested why this peace of code works at all and prints the same tables.

```lua
t = {

    f = function()
        return t
    end

}

print(t)
print(t.f())
```

My assumption was that `t` is only accessible after its definition, thus `return t` should fail. However this code seems to contradict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no local variable `t` in your example, your function accesses the *global* value `t` (that is: `_ENV.t`). When your function is called, it accesses the current value of the _ENV variable, then indexes into the `"t"` index of that _ENV value. Even though the _ENV table does not contain `t` when the function is defined, when it is later called, it *does* contain `t`, and so you are able to access your newly defined table.

```
local u = {
    f = function()
        -- Refers to the global variable `t` (that is, _ENV.t).
        -- Whenever the function is called, the *current* value of `t` is returned
        return t 
    end
}

print(u) -- prints table: 0xFOOBAR
print(u.f()) -- prints nil

t = u

print(t) --prints table: 0xFOOBAR
print(t.f()) --prints table: 0xFOOBAR

_ENV = {print = print}
print(u.f()) -- prints nil, since _ENV.t is now nil

local _ENV = {print = print, t = u}
print(u.f()) -- still prints nil, because the function definition used the
             -- _ENV variable that was lexically visible at the function definition,
             -- rather than the new _ENV variable that was just defined.
```

The use of _ENV means that these examples are only valid for Lua 5.2, but the same principle applies for Lua 5.1.

Comment: Thanks! It is clear that your code does what I expected. My point is what I really would like to understand, that why is `t` accessible even it is not created yet.

Comment: @oroszgy: `t` in the function definition refers to the *global* variable `t`, whose value can be changed at a later stage. Before the assignment, the global variable has the value `nil`, after the assignment the variable holds the table. You call the function *after* the assignment, so that is the value that is returned from the function.

Comment: @oroszgy: Lua has *lexical scoping*. The variable that is bound is exactly the most inner visible variable (or the global variable, if no local variable is visible). Whenever the variable is used, the *current* value is used, rather than the value that was present when the variable was first referenced (the variable was first referenced when the function definition was run, in this example).

Comment: @oroszgy: I've removed `local t` from my example. Instead, I've shown an example of calling `f` before `t` has been reassigned. The point is that the *current* value of `_ENV` is used whenever `f` is called.

Comment: Thanks @Mankarse! The key point for me was that the body of `f` is only interpreted when `t.f()` called.

Comment: @oroszgy "Interpreted" could be a misunderstanding here. Before any execution, the entire source code is compiled. The function definition is compiled to always return the value of a specific variable `t`. Lua is "lexically scoped." So, since no other `t` is in scope in your code, the specific variable is the `t` field of the global environment.